# Magento: How can I view product listings from a non-default root category?

Tags: magento

Magento seems to magically map sub-categories of the default category to a url. For example, a product listing for category "Tops" is currently accessible at /tops.

I created a new root category for products that I do no want to show in the 'normal' product listings. I created a sub-category in my new non-default, root category. Let's call this subcategory "hidden". When I browse to /hidden I get a 404 error.

I've tried browsing to catalog/category/view/id/10 and I've created a URL rewrite in "URL Rewrite Management". Still getting a 404

How can I get Magento to list products from another root category?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "Include in Navigation Menu" option under the "General Information" tab is what you're looking for.  The category would still need to be in your store root, but would not display in your navigation.  A store can only have 1 root category and therefore it's not possible to display categories from another root.

The url is actually created from the "URL Key" field.

Comment: "A store can only have 1 root category" - what's the point of more than one root category in that case?

Comment: Magento is designed to handle multiple stores, and therefore you would need multiple roots.  Store A -> Root A, Store B -> Root B, etc.  In a single store setup I guess there probably isn't much use.  It would allow you to restructure the hierarchy of your whole catalog and then push "live" by changing to the new root.